# I have an excel file that has texts and calculations, what's the best way to read the excel file in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, excel-formula

My excel file doesn't have headers or nice rows and columns.  It also has formulas.  I want to read the values of the formula calculated, not the formula.  What's the best way for python to read the excel file?  I tried openpyxl and can't get pandas to work.

Sample from excel file:

```
    [A]        [B]        [C]             [D]                [E]
[1] Test Case 3 - Step 8                    
[2] Enter the PL, PF, and PR values from the VSWR file below, the formula will calculate the P1 and P2 values that can be entered in the TPR.                   
[3] PL         PF         PR              P1 = (VL*IL)/2     P2 = PL = PF-PR    
[4] 39.3470    39.4508    0.1038          39.3994            39.3470    
[5]                     
[6] Test Case 3 - Step 9                    
[7] The formula will compare the P1 and P2 values calculate above and determine if they are within the tolerance of 10%.                    
[8] |P1-P2|    % Diff     Tolerance 5.0%            
[9] 0.0524     0.1332%    PASS
```

Rows 1, 2, 6, and 7 only contain texts and are on column one.
Rows 3 and 8 are texts showing the formulas in columns A-E.
Cells A4, B4 and C4 contain data entered.
Cells D4, E4, A9, B9 and C9 contains the values after formulas are evaluated.

Code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wbt = load_workbook(filename = "Power_Assurance_Results.xlsx")
wst = wbt.active
Total_Power_Diff = wst['B9'].value
Total_Power_Test = wst['B28'].value
```

I need to get the values of the data in rows 4 and 9.
For Total_Power_Diff, I'm getting the formula =A9/E4 and not the value 0.001332.
For Total_Power_Test, I'm getting None.  The formula on C9 is =IF(B9 <= 0.05,"PASS","FAIL").
I can't figure out how I would use pandas to read this kind of excel file. I thought I read that I can get the evaluated value from the cell and not the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openpyxl is for reading formula, and pandas would get you the numbers excel calculated at save. you will want to use both, use pandas to get numbers, and use openpyxl to edit number and save. Unless you are only doing read then don't worry about openpyxl.

Now, why pandas doesn't work for you?

```
import pandas as pd
wbt = pd.read_excel('Power_Assurance_Results.xlsx')
wbt.head()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, from every example I see, I thought pandas could only be used for nice excel files with columns and headers.  How would I get the value of a cell location?  when I use ```wbt.loc[7][0]```, I get nan.  How do I get the value at that location?

Comment: in yout case, try to use wbt.head(10) and see which row and column your data is actually stored in. and maybe you want to also change the read_excel to indicate no header. wbt = pd.read_excel('Power_Assurance_Results.xlsx', header = False)

Comment: Thank you again.  The ```header=False``` worked and I was able to get the value and not nan.

Comment: Awesome! Please check my answer if you are done, I'm trying to see how much point I could get in a month. :)